# What is the best way to manage messy data onto a UITableView with sections?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tableview, sorting

I am developing an iPhone Application for my school, and I want to make a Table View with all of the teacher names, I read the teacher names from the website, but unfortunately all the data is all scrambled up. **What I need to know is what is the best way to manage this information and put it inside a table view with sorting and sections. And also, how would I make a certain cell take you to a link when the user taps on it?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? NSArray has several sorting methods you can use. The UITableViewDelegate defines methods to override user actions such as clicking on a cell.

Comment: I think someone down-voted your question because you haven't provided enough information.  How is the data scrambled?  What way do you want to present it in the table? Alphabetically?  By teacher pay grade?  Something else?

Comment: It's usually best to split multiple questions into multiple posts instead of asking them all together.  This more easily enables future visitors of the site to find individual answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSSortDescriptor

The API documenation is available at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html